# csrf token is changing where it shouldn't be changed

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm running code below to prevent CSRF vulnerability

```php
if (!isset($_POST['_token'])) {
    $_SESSION['_token'] = bin2hex(random_bytes(20));
}
```

and i am using the token in hidden inputs named _token. I use the following code in my main.js file so that the user can add the product to their favorites.

```js
const wishlist = {
    'add': function (id) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'api/wishlist?method=add',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: 'id=' + id + '&_token=' + $('input[name="_token"]').val(),
            success: function (response) {
                 console.log(response)
            }
        })
    },
    'remove': function (id) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'api/wishlist?method=remove',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: id,
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response)
            }
        })
    }
};
```

Below is the code in wishlist.php which ajax request goes to

```php
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST') {
    header('Location:' . site_url('404'));
}
if (!isset($_POST['_token']) or $_POST['_token'] != $_SESSION['_token']) {
    die('Invalıd CSRF Token!');
}

if ($_GET['method'] == 'add') {
    $json['method'] = "adding to favorites";
}
if ($_GET['method'] == 'remove') {
    $json['method'] = "removeing from favorites";
}
```

The all code is this but sometimes this code works sometimes it gives Invalid csrf token error and sometimes it works for 3-5 times and gives error again.

Comment: Is the typo `$_SESION['_token']` in wishlist.php, not equal check only in the example or in the actual code?

Comment: that's not in the actual code im updating it

Comment: are you using Laravel?

Comment: no i don't use any framework the problem is in init.php     $_SESSION['_token'] = bin2hex(random_bytes(20)); executes even if there is a $_POST['_token'] but i don't know why

Comment: use session_start();

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. It was because client is trying to access to an non-exist file
so that that request executes init.php